# NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject keeps returning NO

Tags: ios, nskeyedarchiver

I've spent the past few hours trying to figure this out, but I've ran out of ideas.

All I'm trying to do is archive an object, but the method `archiveRootObject` keeps on returning `NO`

Here's my code:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *cacheDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
cacheDirectory = [cacheDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"MyAppCache"];
NSString *fullPath = [cacheDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"archive.data"];

if(![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:fullPath]){
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:fullPath withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:nil];
}

NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"hello", @"world", nil];
NSLog(@"Full Path: %@", fullPath);
BOOL res = [NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:array toFile:fullPath];

if(res){
    NSLog(@"YES");
}else{
    NSLog(@"NO");
}
```

Every time time I run this, it prints `NO`.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You create a directory with the path `fullPath` and then you try to write the file at the same path. Overwriting a directory with a file like this is not possible. Use your `cacheDirectory` string to create your directory.

Comment: Almost pulled my hair out. Thank you Sven!

Answer (score 1):

NSString *cacheDirectory is not a mutable string and after you init it, you attempt to modify it so you are writing to the top-level directory.

For a quick fix, try:

```
NSArray *documentPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory,   NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentPath = ([documentPaths count] > 0) ? [documentPaths objectAtIndex:0] : nil;
NSString *documentsResourcesPath = [documentPath  stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"MyAppCache"];

NSString *fullPath = [documentsResourcesPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"archive.data"];
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion Jim, I tried your suggestion but it didn't work. Turns out Sven found the bug. My code is trying to overwrite a directory with a file.

Comment: Well, my code works but I neglected to change the create directory code to use the correct iVAR.      
    if(![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:fullPath]){
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:documentsResourcesPath withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:nil];  Good luck and best regards,  Jim

Comment: This worked for me when saving data though how would you load data from this? Thanks in advance.