# NSKeyedArchiver.archiveRootObject returns "false" if I want to overwrite data, why?

Tags: swift, xcode6, nskeyedarchiver, ios9.1

```
NSKeyedArchiver.archiveRootObject(<#rootObject: AnyObject#>, toFile: <#String#>)
```

Only returns true the first time. Every next time I call it, the method returns false.

I read some SO, some posts said that I can't rewrite data this way. However, I tried :

```
 NSFileManager.defaultManager().removeItemAtPath(path, error: nil)
```

and it still didn't help.

What I did:

1. Checked all my model files for the `NSCoding` protocol
2. Checked all my `required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)` and `func encodeWithCoder(aCoder: NSCoder)`

I am missing something, since I have done this in my last app and it worked fla`

```
import Foundation

    private let ON_DISK_DATA_DICTIONARY    = "savedDataPathsOnDisk"
    private let _WBMAccessDataOnDiskMShared = WBMAccessDataOnDiskM()
    private var dataDirectories:NSArray!   = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)
    private var dataDirectoryURL:NSURL!    = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: dataDirectories.objectAtIndex(0) as! String, isDirectory: true)
    private var dataDirectoryPath:String!  = dataDirectoryURL.path!

    let FILE_FORMAT = ".archive"

    class WBMAccessDataOnDiskM: NSObject
    {
        class var sharedData: WBMAccessDataOnDiskM
        {
            return _WBMAccessDataOnDiskMShared
        }

        private var dataAndPathDictionary = [String:String]()

        func getDataAndPathDictionary() -> [String:String]
        {
            return self.dataAndPathDictionary
        }

        func addDataAndPathToDictionary(data:String ,path:String)
        {
            if !checkIfDataAllreadyExists(data)
            {
                let fullPath                = createFullDataPath(path)
                dataAndPathDictionary[data] = fullPath
                NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(dataAndPathDictionary, forKey: ON_DISK_DATA_DICTIONARY)
            }
        }

        func checkIfDataIsAvailable(dataPathComponent:String) -> (Bool,String)
        {
            var paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0] as! String
            var dataPath = paths.stringByAppendingPathComponent(dataPathComponent)
            var checkValidation = NSFileManager.defaultManager()

            println(dataPathComponent)

            if (checkValidation.fileExistsAtPath(dataPath))
            {
                return (true,dataPath)
            }
            else
            {
                return (false,"")
            }
        }

        func checkForDataOnDisk() -> Bool
        {
            let dataDict = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey(ON_DISK_DATA_DICTIONARY) as? [String:String]

            if dataDict == nil
            {
                return false
            }
            else
            {
                dataAndPathDictionary = dataDict!
                return true
            }
        }

        private func checkIfDataAllreadyExists(data:String) -> Bool
        {
            let keys = self.dataAndPathDictionary.keys.array
            if contains(keys, data)
            {
                return true
            }
            return false
        }

        private func createFullDataPath(path:String) -> String
        {
            var fullPathURL = dataDirectoryURL.URLByAppendingPathComponent(path + FILE_FORMAT)
            return fullPathURL.path!
        }

        func saveDataArray(data:[AnyObject], path:String)
        {
            NSFileManager.defaultManager().removeItemAtPath(path, error: nil)

            if NSKeyedArchiver.archiveRootObject(data, toFile: path)
            {
               // SAVING
                println(" Saving data ARRAY ")
            }
            else
            {
                println(" NOT saving data ARRAY ")
            }
        }

        func saveDataObject(dataObject:AnyObject, path:String)
        {
            if NSKeyedArchiver.archiveRootObject(dataObject, toFile: path)
            {
                println(" Saving data OBJECT ")
            }
            else
            {
                println(" NOT saving data OBJECT ")
            }
        }

        // dataFromDisk = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithFile(pathForNews) as? [AnyObject]
        func loadDataArray(path:String) -> [AnyObject]?
        {
            var dataArrayFromDisk: [AnyObject]?
            dataArrayFromDisk = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithFile(path) as? [AnyObject]

            return dataArrayFromDisk
        }

        func loadDataObject(path:String) -> AnyObject?
        {
            var dataObjectFromDisk: AnyObject?
            dataObjectFromDisk = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithFile(path)
            return dataObjectFromDisk
        }

        func getNewsDataLanguagePath() -> String
        {
            var currentOSLanguage = LOCALIZATION.currentOsLanguage
            currentOSLanguage     = currentOSLanguage.substringToIndex(2)
            if currentOSLanguage == "de"
            {
                return ON_DISK_CONTENT_DE
            }
            else if currentOSLanguage == "en"
            {
                return ON_DISK_CONTENT_ENG
            }
            return ON_DISK_CONTENT_ENG
        }
    `
```

I am using Xcode 6.4 and Swift 1.2.

Any help & code correction is welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Because of the code you put here does't contain the call of `saveDataArray` or `saveDataObject` so I judge that you have maintain the path of a archived object manually.**This is where thing went wrong.** The method of NSKeyedArchiver named `archiveRootObject` can automatically maintain the archiver file path.

In the Apple's doucumet

> Archives an object graph rooted at a given object by encoding it into a data object then atomically writes the resulting data object to a file at a given path, and returns a Boolean value that indicates whether the operation was successful.

And there is another question in [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14326696/4383896) may help you.

Comment: I will test it as soon as possilbe. Ty

Answer (score 0):

I followed apple instructions in this good example: [Persist Data](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/Lesson10.html)
But I had the same problem you describe with my app for AppleTV. At the end I change .Documents directory for CacheDirectory and it's working well.

```
static let DocumentsDirectorio = NSFileManager().URLsForDirectory(.CachesDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask).first!
```